# Piwik API. Мильтизапросы или как объединить несколько запросов в один?

Tags: статистика, php, оптимизация

Здравствуйте.

**Краткое вступление**

В своем проекте я использую для сбора статистики такую штуку - [Piwik](http://piwik.org/). Причины столь необычного решения в данном случае значения не имеют. У этой системы есть одна замечательная вещь - Piwik API, которая предоставляет доступ к статистике и позволяет перенести саму систему статистики на другой сервер.

**Ближе к делу**

Для получения каких-либо данных реализуются запросы к модулям и их действиям. Пример:

```
$unique_visitors = $this->piwik->sendRequest('VisitsSummary.getUniqueVisitors', array(
   'idSite' => $piwik_site_id,
   'period' => 'day',
   'date'   => $date
));

$orders = $this->piwik->sendRequest('Goals.get', array(
   'idSite' => $piwik_site_id,
   'period' => 'day',
   'date'   => $date,
   'idGoal' => 'ecommerceOrder'
));
```

Моя проблема заключается в том, что для получения каждого типа статистки нужно делать отдельный запрос к системе, и получается, что для формирования одной таблицы нужно делать несколько запросов. Это очень плохо сказывается на времени формирования страницы. И вынесения этих фич в ajax не особо помогает - время загрузки в 10-20 секунд.

**И чего ты от нас хочешь?**

*Есть ли какой-то способ объединить несколько запросов в один, чтобы сервер статистики одновременно возвращал набор данных по этим запросам?*

**П.С.**

Я понимаю, что это редко используемая система, поэтому я максимально подробно описал, о чем идет речь и чего я хочу добиться, для тех, кто не работал с Piwik'ом, но решал подобные задачи в других областях или системах.

Comment: C Piwik'ом не знаком, но что мешает кэшировать запросы (напр в бд). При загрузке страницы выводить данные из кэша, и если он устарел, передавать клиенту пометку что необходимо обновить данные через ajax, после чего пользователь через js дернет Ваш сервер с требованием получить новые данные из Piwik, пока сервер будет запрашивать свежие данные, пользователь будет видеть "старые" данные, и как только сервер получит все нужное, отдаст их клиенту и обновит их в кэше, после чего пользователь увидит свежие данные. Ну или использовать cron для обновления кэша.

Comment: Это не столько решение, сколько - "выкрутиться во что бы это ни стало". Костыли. Предполагается многопользовательская система, и для каждого пользователя будет своя статистика. А поскольку статистика будет пересчитываться каждый час, самим piwik'ом, пользователю придется регулярно "ждать" обновления. Или гонять скрипт кеширования по крону, а это лишняя нагрузка на сервер. Но как вариант "Безысходность" я его рассмотрю)